# Is there a constant for the current "system foreground" color in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In windows (UWP / WPF) I have constants like WindowsTextBrush, ActiveCaptionBrush and so on.
When I set this as color for a TextBox and the user changes his System Colors (form for an example Black on White to Green on Black) the color of my TextBox changes automatically.

I can't find a thing like this on Android using Xamarin.
My case - I created a Homescreen-Widget which has some text on it. When I change my system settings to "Dark Mode" all launcher Icons on my home-screen get a white label color. Opposite - if I change to "Light Mode" they become black.

I want my Widget-Text also to adapt to this color. Is there a constant like in windows, or what do I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: could it help you ?

Answer (score 1):

> The DayNight Theme was added to AppCompat with the realease of Support
>   Library v23.2.0

We can reference the theme using **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight**. DayNight theme allows to switch between light(day) and dark(night) themes, based on the time. Keep in mind that it supports API 14+. Any lower and it defaults to the Light theme.

So you can change the theme according to the system DayNight mode, of course, this requires you to do the configuration of DayNight.

you could refer to :https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/daynight-theme-android-tutorial-example/
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94

Comment: I don't want to switch to day / night. What I'm talking about is Dark Mode https://9to5google.com/2018/12/17/android-dark-mode-theme-pie/

Comment: @ManniAT i know,but each of the options map directly to one of the AppCompat.DayNight modes:`Light - MODE_NIGHT_NO`,`Dark - MODE_NIGHT_YES`,`Set by Battery`,`Saver - MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY`,`System default - MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`
To switch the theme, call `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()`. you could refer to [Dark Theme](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme),you also could saw that in your link